# Creating new kafka topic using nifi

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I'm trying to put some data into an uncreated Kafka topic using the PublishKafka_2.0 processor in Nifi.

I don't have a direct approach to the Kafka server - only via the nifi flow, and i need to create 3 new topics for the data.

How can it be done using nifi??

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to enable automatic creation of Kafka topics from Kafka itself. NiFi doesn't have any control over Kafka. It just supports consuming and producing. From the sound of it, you may have a setup where automatic topic creation is disabled, so you'll need to have someone create the topics for you.

Comment: Not sure auto topics is really the recommended approach because you'd have no control over partition count or replication factor

Comment: You can set defaults for these - but either way that becomes a Kafka management discussion rather than NiFi, who is but a producer/consumer, not a Kafka management tool.